# High Power DC motor current control

Tags: current-measurement, motor-controller

I need to monitor a high power DC motor with 48V and 600A battery, if it's stalled or not (its a lift truck).
The driver is 25 parallel MOSFET with Rds(on)=7.6e-47 which control by 15kHz PWM.
I think because of high current, i cannot use shunt resistor to check the current.
any bright idea?

Comment: Could you double check that Rds(on) value, please, and provide a link to the datasheet? **Why** do you think that you cannot use a shunt? What problems do you expect?

Comment: Is your MOSFET a superconductor‽ That \$R_{DS,on}\$ value is several different kinds of absurd, and I suspect you made a mistake in reading the datasheet, or just a typo.

Comment: for driving such high current motor, there are 25 parallel MOSFET. Each mosfet has 0.015 Rds(on).

Answer (score 0):

DC current sensing is commonly done with [Hall-effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall_effect) current sensors.

[image]

*Figure 1. Various types of Hall-effect current sensors.*

The units shown are from the LEM range and are used for all sorts of applications from small to electric train traction monitoring. One of the big advantages over shunts is the complete isolation it offers between the control and power circuits.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that Hall effect current sensors tend to be less accurate (not to mention more expensive) than direct current-shunt sensing, so if that is an option that would probably be preferred.